# Business card height and width in pixels on web?

Tags: html, css, web, printing

i Need Business card height and width in pixels on web, because i have created business card design by HTML and CSS in my application. here i can give print commend to print business card.

Now whats the width and height in pixel i use, so that it will correctly printed on actual business card size (3.5 and 2 inch)

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
height: 336px
width: 192
```

=

```
height: 3.5in
width: 2in
```

Comment: How did you decide the conversion from inch to pixels without knowing the DPI he is printing at?

Comment: He's asking "Now whats the width and height in pixel i use".

Answer (score 1):

Inches are valid CSS lengths just use those.

> **Absolute length units** represents a physical measurement and when the physical properties of the output medium are known, such as for print layout. This is done by anchored one of the unit to a physical unit and to defined the other relatively to it. The anchor is done differently for low-resolution devices, like screens, and high-resolution devices, like printers.

[**Length @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

> **CSS units and dots-per-inch**
>
> The unit *in/inch* doesn't represent a physical inch on screen, but represents 96px. That means that whatever is the real screen pixel density, it is assumed to be 96dpi. On devices with a greater pixel density, 1in will be smaller than 1 physical inch. Similarly mm, cm, and pt are not absolute length.
>
> Some specific examples:
>
> 1in is always 96px, 3pt is always 4px, 25.4mm is always 96px.

Comment: You should emphasize, "On devices with a greater pixel density, 1in will be smaller than 1 physical inch." which is why the W3C says not to do that. http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html